# Ensure user inputs text in INPUT Box in CAPS

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I have a input box that the user needs to put in some specific text. The text must be in uppercase. But when i run the code and insert the text in lower case, it still runs.

```
HERE:
            KnownError = InputBox(PayRatesTable.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange(i) & " is showing " 
            & PayRatesTable.ListColumns("Hourly or Salary").DataBodyRange(i) & " for role " & 
            PayRatesTable.ListColumns("All Roles").DataBodyRange(i) & ". Please type KNOWN ERROR (All 
            CAPS) to 
            continue.")

            If StrPtr(KnownError) = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Process Aborted"
                Exit Sub
            End If

            If KnownError <> "KNOWN ERROR" Then
                MsgBox "Please type KNOWN ERROR (All CAPS) to continue or cancel to stop the 
                proccess"
                GoTo HERE
            End If
```

Any ideas on how to force the use of uppercase??

Comment: If you are going to use an `InputBox` you can just force it to uppercase yourself in code after they enter it using `UCase$()` - is that not the best solution for you? It's certainly the easiest solution.

Comment: Can you confirm you haven't set `Option Compare Text` on a modular level? I agree with @braX that `UCase()` here is easiest. Otherwise use `StrComp` and check binary.

Comment: Instead of 'If KnownError <> "KNOWN ERROR" Then' use 'If StrComp(KnownError, "KNOWN ERROR") <> 0 Then'.

Comment: Hi @VBasic2008, brilliant. Thank You